# DAX Measure to count rows with particular background cell color

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with a column contains different value types, I want to write a DAX measure to count a cell with yellow color. For eg. the Column name is Contract and has a column has three sets of value. 1. Yellow Cell 2. Non-Blank 3. Blank. Yellow signifies Gaps, Non-Blank cell shows the project awarded, Blank cells represent no action. Ideally, I want to count row with a yellow specific color in a card visual. So when I select region it should count the yellow color only. Can anyone from the community give me a hand to create a DAX measure?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi7Ru.png)

Comment: I am assuming this color is conditionally formatted, it would be easier to just count values in the column  using these conditions. I am not sure the other method is even possible. List the conditions and I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.  You are correct, that was my initial thought, below is my measure.

[Gaps by region = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Project_Delivery,Project_Delivery[Contract]="YELLOW"))]

But this leads to manual extra work. The file is pulled from SharePoint, comes in excel format. Don't think it got conditional formatting. Inputter has to add value every time. So my objective is to automate the process.

I'm after DAX measures, so when I select region it should count the yellow color. I'm tweaking my question, the column has three sets of value. 1. Yellow Cell 2. Non-Blank 3. Blank. Yellow signifies Gaps, Non-Blank cell shows the project awarded, Blank cells represent no action.

I'm only looking to count row the number of cells with a yellow specific color in a card visual.

Appreciate your timely advice.

Many Thanks